# MoveToElement only works when using xOffset and yOffset

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

In a sidebar menu I want to move to a menu item. I'm using this code:

@FindBy(xpath = ".//*[@id='sidebar-wrapper']/ul//a[contains(text(), 'Contact')]")
WebElement contactLink;

```
public void clickHamburgerMenuAndContactLink() {
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.click(hamburgerMenu).moveToElement(contactLink, 0, 0).click().perform();

}
```

This works most of the time although it also fails from time to time (behavior seems to be unstable).

First I tried to move without mentioning the x and y Offset using only the webelement contactlink as an argument in the moveToElement method. This don't work at all, I don't understand why. I tried also with build() before the perform() but this makes no difference.

Comment: if you are finding contactLink element after clicking hamburgerMenu element. so why are you not using contactLink.click() directly???

Comment: Can you share the website?

Comment: http://www.turnjavaforus.nl/index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unstable behaviour is probably due to the animation effect which makes the contact link unsteady. I would wait for the close button since it is displayed once the menu reaches its final position:

```java
public void clickHamburgerMenuAndContactLink() {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10000);
    hamburgerMenu.click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("menu-close")));
    contactLink.click();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Florent, this is the solution for my problem. It works great without any hesitation.